# Identifying when a JS script is running as a Worker

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have a script which can be run either directly or, when available in the browser, as a Web Worker. I'd like to run a portion of this script only when run as a worker; so my question is, how can a script identify itself as being run this way?

I can't see anything in the spec that would allow this to happen; am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You could check for existence of a certain property; I believe e.g. `window` is not defined in a worker script (i.e. `typeof window === "undefined" ? worker : normal`). I'm not entirely sure though.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing something like this - as window isn't available in other environments - but I'll probably have to!

Comment: Good point; perhaps `postMessage` is the thing to check existence of.

Comment: Sadly not, as `window.postMesage` is perfectly valid and is used to communicate with cross-domain windows as well as workers. I'll go with checking for `window` for now as I'm not planning to use nodejs any time soon ;)

Comment: Ah of course, I was thinking of something that's available in a worker in all environments - but `postMessage` is of course available in the parent script as well.

Comment: Don't check for the existence of postMessage, as that is explicitly *allowed* in web workers. Try checking for "self" vs "this".

Comment: Geuis, the trouble with that is `self` is a fairly common variable name (often used with closures), so its possible it has been already defined in some horrid jQuery plugin or other. Unless there's something defined in the spec then I reckon checking for `window` is the safest bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Worker</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script >
  var w = new Worker ('worker.js');
  w.onmessage = function (e) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<br>' + 'WORKER : ' + e.data;
  };
</script>
<script src='worker.js'></script>
</html>
```

worker.js is invoked both as a script and as a worker.

worker.js contains :

```
  var msg = 'postMessage is ' + postMessage.toString () + 
          ', self.constructor is ' + self.constructor;
  try {
    postMessage (msg);
  } catch (e) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<br>SCRIPT : ' + msg;
  }
```

In the worker environment, the postMessage succeeds, in the script environment it fails because either it is undefined or, in a browser, it requires a second argument.

Output is :

chrome :

```
SCRIPT : postMessage is function () { [native code] }, self.constructor is function DOMWindow() { [native code] } 
WORKER : postMessage is function postMessage() { [native code] }, self.constructor is function DedicatedWorkerContext() { [native code] }
```

firefox :

```
SCRIPT : postMessage is function postMessage() { [native code] }, self.constructor is [object Window]
WORKER : postMessage is function postMessage() { [native code] }, self.constructor is function DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope() { [native code] }
```

opera:

```
WORKER : postMessage is function postMessage() { [native code] }, self.constructor is function Object() { [native code] }
SCRIPT : postMessage is function postMessage() { [native code] }, self.constructor is function Object() { [native code] }
```

All under Ubuntu.

Comment: Good point regarding the required second argument; that'll do!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) (it is an open-source JavaScript library that helps you NOT to  reinventing the wheel again and again).

```
if (Modernizr.webworkers) {
  // window.Worker is available!
} 
else {
  // no native support for web workers
}
```